# Feed for http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, feed

Is there a feed for https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week ?  If not, can one be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now working; check the footer on the homepage for each tab, there is a unique feed for:

- active (same as before)
- featured
- hot
- week
- month